# check for ipv6 compatiblity with snmp

Tags: snmp, ipv6

Im new to snmp.

Is it possible to check if a device is ipv6 compatilble while on a ipv4 network through snmp?

thanks,
cja100

Comment: maybe I should expand a little more, I am creating a program that will do a network scan and determine if a device supports IPv6. I am thinking of SNMP as a way in to test this, but I want to be able to test if a device supports IPv6 even if IPv6 has been disabled on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the device itself support IPv6? Basically SNMP builds a socket (IP address + Port number). This means that either IPv6:Port and IPv4:Port should behave the same. But the device should have the ability to configure a IPv6 address or supports IPv6 for link local connections. If the device does not have this then also SNMP won't have support for IPv6.

Comment: Are you saying I can try to connect to a device through IPv6 by only knowing its IPv4 address?

Comment: I think I got a little bit wrong. I thought you want to access SNMP via IPv6. Sorry for that. :-)
You would like to know if IPv6 is supported by the device. If you're on the same subnet you can make use of the IPv6 Neighbor Discovery Protocol. This means that all IPv6 capable nodes can discover each other in a broadcast domain. You can monitor the network traffic while plugging in a PC or Notebook which has IPv6 enabled. It will start a  discovery and the other device(s) should answer if all devices are configured correctly.

Comment: Nice I didn't know about that, so that helps me if IPv6 is enabled but what about devices that support IPv6 but it is disabled by default, such as routers?

Comment: I think in the end you have to check the manual. Or you get a complete list of the SNMP informations and walk your way through it if maybe one value is assigned to IPv6. But I think it's way more faster to just check the support manuals of the device. ;-)